# is it possible to get exactly the same results from tf.signal.frame followed by tf.signal.rfft and librosa.stft?

Tags: tensorflow, fft, frame, librosa

I have calculated stft by initially framing the audio signal using tf.signal.frame and applying Real-valued fast Fourier transform over each frame using  tf.signal.rfft.

code look like :

```
audio =  'fileid_0.wav'
sig, rate =librosa.core.load(audio, 16000,mono=True)
blockLen = 512
block_shift = 128
frames = tf.signal.frame(sig, blockLen, block_shift)
stft_dat = tf.signal.rfft(frames)
```

Then I calculated stft using librosa

```
stft_librosa = librosa.stft(sig,n_fft=512, hop_length=128, win_length=512,center=False)
```

But the results from both these approach is different. How can I make it same

Answer (score 0):

To make it same, there are two approaches

1. Apply `hann_windows` to the frame before doing the rfft

   ```
   w = tf.signal.hann_window(512, periodic=True)
   ```

   ***or***
2. Set the `window` in `librosa.stft` to `rect`

   ```
   librosa.stft(sig,n_fft=512,hop_length=128,center=False,window='rect')
   ```